# Como mudar o valor de uma variável no terminal do python e salvar permanentemente?

Tags: python

Alguém sabe como mudar o valor de uma variável no terminal e ficar salva para sempre no script?

ex: Eu crio uma variável do tipo input ps: O nome da variável é Nome;

```
E depois crio uma variável com o nome recebe;

A variável recebe a variável Nome;

E quando fecho o terminal do python, a variavel recebe estará o oque eu escrevi no terminal.
```

Comment: A pergunta não está muito clara, poderia [edit] e explicar melhor, por favor? Se estiver falando do REPL do Python, acho que o que você quer não é possível.

Comment: Não é possível mesmo, se você quer persistir o valor de uma variável quando o programa não estiver mais executando, precisa salvar esse valor em algum lugar (arquivo, banco de dados), e ler desse lugar para obter o valor salvo caso exista.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como voce que algo simples voce pode usar um arquivo para salvar, mas quando vc quiser salvar dados em modo persistente aconselho usar algum SGBD.

```
#ler nome do arquivo
with open('data.txt','r') as f:
    name = f.read()
#imprime na tela
print('Atual:')
print(name)
new_name = input('Qual o seu nome:')
with open('data.txt','w') as f:
    f.write(new_name)
```

lembre-se de criar o arquivo data.txt na mesma pasta do codigo e rode em python3